# lock(this) in singleton pattern

Tags: c#, singleton

Is using lock(this) instead of lock(lockObject) good implementation in a singleton lazy multi thread implementation?

example:

```
    public class MedicineHelper
    {
        private static MedicineHelper medicineHelper;
        private MedicineHelper()
        {
        }

        public static MedicineHelper GetInstance()
        {
            if (medicineHelper == null)
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    if (medicineHelper == null) medicineHelper = new MedicineHelper();
                }
            }
            return medicineHelper;
        }
    }
```

The classical pattern require a lock dedicated object like this:

```
    public class MedicineHelper
    {
        private static MedicineHelper medicineHelper;
        private static Object lockObject = new Object();
        private MedicineHelper()
        {
        }

        public static MedicineHelper GetInstance()
        {
            if (medicineHelper == null)
            {
                lock (LockObject)
                {
                    if (medicineHelper == null) medicineHelper = new MedicineHelper();
                }
            }
            return medicineHelper;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well your examples are wrong. **GetInstance()** should be **static**

Comment: And to build off of @MickyD, notice what happens when you correct your `GetInstance()` method signature.  There's your answer.

Comment: Once you make it static, it should answer your question. Your first scenario once modified, won't compile

Comment: yes should be static, i fix it now the example

Comment: Don't explicitly lock at all, just initialize the static field instead of declaring it without initializing it.

Comment: As the others already commented: you did _not_ fix your example. This now won't compile. You cannot `lock(this)` in a _static_ method.

Comment: I suggest [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

Comment: @Servy actually static field initialisation isn't recommended by MS for multithreaded scenarios. Instead they recommend _double-check locking_. See Rene's link

Comment: @MickyD Sounds like you need to go read the article again.  It specifically suggests using that approach in most situations, mentioning that there are only rare exceptional situations in which it isn't suitable (none of which appear to apply here).

Comment: The code you've included here doesn't compile. Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly the two _working_ scenarios you wish to compare. Please also note that even if you do manage to get two working scenarios to compare, lacking a precise _problem statement_ it is likely any answer would be "primarily opinion based".

Comment: @Servy OP is asking for MT solution so then when you consider _"[Static initialization is suitable for most situations. When your application must delay the instantiation, use a non-default constructor or perform other tasks before the instantiation, and work in a **multithreaded environment, you need a different solution**.    ...One of the more common solutions is to use the **Double-Check Locking**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)"_.  The fact then that the article appears to contradict itself by saying it's "rarely" required without saying _why_ is somewhat lacking

Comment: @Servy _"rare exceptional situations in which it isn't suitable (none of which appear to apply here)"_ - out of respect and for my own personal learning, a link to a article on this would be useful. Thanks Servy :)

Comment: @MickyD "When your application must delay the instantiation" There is no need here.  From the article: "Static Initialization [...] The only potential downside of this approach is that you have less control over the mechanics of the instantiation. [...]  static initialization is the preferred approach for implementing a Singleton in .NET. [...] Static initialization is suitable for most situations. [...] double-check locking approach [...]  In practice, an application rarely requires this type of implementation. In most cases, the static initialization approach is sufficient."

Comment: @MickyD "The fact then that the article appears to contradict itself by saying it's "rarely" required without saying why is somewhat lacking" *You just quoted the reason why* in the excerpt you posted here.  It does not contradict itself at all.

Comment: @Servy Ah thanks Servy, I understand now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good implementation because you can't do it. "this" is not available from a static method.